# Gridview to excel export discard decimal values

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel

I want that cell should fomrat number from 12.5 to 12 in gridview to excel export.
I found one solution is 
    gridRow.Cells(6).Attributes.Add("mso-number-format","0") 
but it rounds 12.5 to 13

Comment: make your own function that your gridRow.Cells as param ..

Answer (score 0):

The only format for excel available as shown in the link below

[Excel Format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/use-formatting-to-change-the-way-numbers-dates-times-and-text-appear-in-microsoft-excel-HA001126989.aspx#BM1)

In your case what you can do is to trim the decimal part and then export it to excel

Comment: thanks but here scenario is gridview export is generating excel after excel export user is entering data i want that on a particular column data entered on a cell should get formatted from 12.5 or 12.8 to 12 i.e. i want only floor value of it truncating decimal value